# проблема с выводом информации из API

Tags: python, json, discord.py, requests

Бот должен парсить информацию с https://api.wynncraft.com/v2/player/PlayRW/stats но вместо PlayRW должен быть ник, который человек впишет после $stats. Бот все время выводит No data avaible.

отрывок из кода main.py:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import parsing

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):  #таб есть если что  
if message.content.startswith(f'$stats'):
        word = message.content.split("$stats", 1)[1]
        
        try:
            await message.channel.send(f'**Stats of {word}:** ' + "```" + str(parsing.stats(word))[:1500].replace(',', '\n').replace(']', '\n').replace('}', '').replace("'", "").replace('{', '\n').replace('[', '\n') + "```")
        except:
            await message.channel.send('```Error 01: type $stats "name"```')
````

код  parsing.py:

```
import requests
import json
import threading

def stats(argument):
    threading.Timer(10.0, f).start()
    link = 'https://api.wynncraft.com/v2/player/' + argument + '/stats'
    a = requests.get(link)
    res = json.loads(a.text)
    if res['data']:
        user = f'name:  {res["data"][0]["username"]}'
        is_online = f'online:  {res["data"][0]["meta"]["location"]["online"]}'
        playtime = f'playtime(bug): {res["data"][0]["meta"]["playtime"]}'
        rank = f'rank: {res["data"][0]["meta"]["tag"]["value"]}'
        return user, is_online, playtime, rank
    else:
        return f'No data available.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main.py

````
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import parsing

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$stats'):
        word = message.content.split("$stats", 1)[1].strip()

        try:
            stats_result = parsing.stats(word)
            if stats_result != 'No data available.':
                formatted_message = f'**Stats of {word}:** ' + "```" + '\n'.join(stats_result) + "```"
            else:
                formatted_message = 'No data available.'

            await message.channel.send(formatted_message)
        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send(f'```Error: {e}```')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run('YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN')
````

parsing.py

```
 import requests

def stats(argument):
    link = f'https://api.wynncraft.com/v2/player/{argument}/stats'
    response = requests.get(link)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        res = response.json()
        if res['data']:
            user = f'name: {res["data"][0]["username"]}'
            is_online = f'online: {res["data"][0]["meta"]["location"]["online"]}'
            playtime = f'playtime: {res["data"][0]["meta"]["playtime"]}'
            rank = f'rank: {res["data"][0]["meta"]["tag"]["value"]}'
            return user, is_online, playtime, rank
        else:
            return 'No data available.'
    else:
        return f'Error fetching data: HTTP {response.status_code}'
```